# Embed a page on a standard built-In object layout

Tags: managed-package, page-layout, visualforce

I have a page in a managed package and I want to embed it within the standard lead detail view. One way to do this is something like this (taken from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/overrides_2.htm)):

- From the object management settings for accounts, go to Page Layouts.
- Click Edit next to Account Layout.
- Select Visualforce Pages in the left column of the user interface elements palette.

Is it possible to do these steps automatically during package install? So that the standard layout includes custom page when package is installed and there is no need for our users to perform any manual configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is work as designed as SFDC don't upgrade the layouts. because some customers don't like the page layout updated automatically, it instantly changes what their end users experience when they upgrade the package.

Here is the ref document what is allowed and what is not allowed from managed package

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm

Answer (score 1):

As per below document page layout setting is determined by package creator.

**Page layout settings—determined by the package creator**

So if it was determined by package creator you do not need to manually align your Layout page.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.appExchangeInstallGuide.meta/appExchangeInstallGuide/appexchange_install_installation.htm